# Both BigDecimal and DecimalFormat give wrong output

Tags: javafx, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I've done a lot of research on this, but I just can't seem to get the right answer. I need the final result to be in a specific format, but no matter what I do, my code doesn't work for larger numbers. It works for small numbers, but for larger ones it messes up and prints the results plus many unnecessary zeroes. I've tried everything from DecimalFormat to BigDecimal, but nothing seems to be working!

I need the result to be in the format of, for example, $1,138.43. Here's the important part of the code:

```
        double x = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        double y = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());
        double z = Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());
        double res = x * (1 + (z / (12 * 100)));
        double power = y * 12;
        double fin = Math.pow(res, power);
        t4.setText("$" + fin);
```

What I've tried so far:

```
t4.setText(new DecimalFormat("$#.00").format(fin));
```

and

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(fin);
t4.setText("$" + bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

and also a few combinations with strings and DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out I set the calculations wrong! I needed to do this instead:

```
        double x = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        double y = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());
        double z = Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());
        double w = (1 + (z / (12 * 100)));
        double power = y * 12;
        double m = Math.pow(w, power);
        double fin = x * m;
        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(fin);
        t4.setText(new DecimalFormat(",###.##").format(bd));
```